# Hierarchical Views Catalog using Taxonomy in Drupal 8

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8, views

I have the following Taxonomy vocabulary named *Product Catagories*:

Categorie1

- Sub categorie1
- Sub categorie1

Categorie2

- Sub categorie2
- Sub categorie2

If the user click on e.g. *Categorie1* I want to show the child-terms of *Categorie1* in a view.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1jqu8JnLbU) and configured all steps. But in **Drupal 8** I cant't find this step:

> Default validation criteria" for "Taxonomy term" and choose "Convert
>   taxonomy name to ID

Where is a similar option like *Convert taxonomy name to ID* in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubercart for Drupal 8 has a catalog example that might be a solution for you

https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/ubercart-8.x-4.0-alpha4.tar.gz

Comment: But what about Drupal 8? It must have a solution to make (categorie) pages based on taxonomy parents and childs?

Comment: Install ubercart for Drupal 8  open views and there will be a view called catalog that is a working example  of what I believe you want        duplicate the page as a block and place it in sidebar with catalog page

Comment: It also has a vocabulary called catalog that you can add your terms to right out of the box

Comment: I just installed Ubercart for Drupal 8. It doesn't add any view? It also doesn't add a Taxonomy vocabulary? Did you installed the Drupal 8 version? Do you get the view installed?

Comment: Ubercart is a collection of modules  and Ubercart catalog is  grouped under   Ubercart - Core (Optional)  and must be enabled  just type catalog  in the extend  filter box and you should see it     just enable it and catalog view will be avaliable

Comment: Thanks! I found it en tested it! But also Ubercart is using term ID, like category/1 instead of category/term-name. How do I convert term ID to term name?

Comment: do you have a solution how to rewrite the path from `catalog/1` to `catalog/apples`?

Comment: Use pathauto and tokens

Comment: I use path auto pattern for this vocabulary. But when I enter URL `catalog/1` I see my view with all my child-terms in a nice grid. But if enter URL `catalog/apples` it's not loading the view grid. I think it's going to the page of the taxonomy term?

Comment: Don't use pathauto to generate an alias for catalog term 
Use pathauto on content  somthing like  /catalog_item/[node:title]
But that is not what you want
Do look for a block called (catalog  in catagory catalog)  in the block layout place block
It is a hierarchical menu block for the catalog page and has options
place it in a sidebar and that with breadcrumbs gives you a navigable page